# Select GPU during execution in Theano

Tags: python, gpu, theano, lasagne

I am training neural nets with theano and lasagne on a 4 GPU machine. My `.theanorc` contains the following lines:

```
[global]
device = gpu0
```

So when in python I execute  `import theano`, I get `Using gpu device 0: GRID K520`

What if, after importing theano, I chose to use say gpu1? I'd like to do this dynamically, that is, without editing `.theanorc` is it possible? Or even to choose it at runtime?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible to change the execution device after Theano has been imported. From the [documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html):

> config.device
>
> String value: either 'cpu', 'gpu', 'gpu0', 'gpu1',
> 'gpu2', or 'gpu3'
>
> [...]
>
> *This flag’s value cannot be modified during
> the program execution.*

**Bonus**: however, let's say you wanted to have two Python processes each running on a separate GPU (is that what you want?), then you could do something like:

```
import os
os.system("THEANO_FLAGS='device=gpu0' python myscript.py")
os.system("THEANO_FLAGS='device=gpu1' python myscript.py")
```

or hack into/extend Python's [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html) module (which works by spawning subprocesses) to ensure the flag is set before a child process is spawned.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT:
Theano is now based on the GPU array backend and the following API is no longer available.

As @EelkeSpaak mentioned, you can't change the GPU device after theano was imported. But if you want to choose it programmatically before that's possible without changing environment variables.

1. Make sure you're not choosing a device in your .theanorc file. 
   So nothing like:

   `device=gpu`
2. before calling `import theano` choose the GPU device as follows:

   ```
   import theano.sandbox.cuda
   theano.sandbox.cuda.use('gpu1')

   #Results in Using gpu device 1: Tesla K80
   ```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `RuntimeError: ('initCnmem: cnmemInit call failed! Reason=CNMEM_STATUS_OUT_OF_MEMORY. numdev=1\n', 'You asked to force this device and it failed. No fallback to the cpu or other gpu device.')`. This was after the first import statement, couldn't even get to setting the gpu.

Comment: @Sachin_ruk that's a different issue. You might want to ask a new question.